# Tweets in Wordpress without plugins

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter

Is there a PHP or whatever solution to display my tweets in Wordpress **WITHOUT** the use for a Plugin?

**EDIT**
I was using this, but now randomly stopped working, (scroll to number 6)
http://www.instantshift.com/2009/05/25/10-twitter-hacks-for-your-wordpress-blog/

Comment: Are you looking to hard-code the functionality? Displaying tweets either require you to download a page with your tweets (twitter.com/yourusername) or use the OAuth-library to pull the data that way.

Comment: why the requirement of no plugin? A plugin is nothing more then a complicated way to add code. How is just adding code in the non-preferred way better?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're looking for http://twitter.com/about/resources/widgets/widget_profile

Answer (score 0):

You can use a JQuery Script to retrieve your tweets form twitter without any WP Plugin or php code.

http://tweet.seaofclouds.com/